# How do I get Average Volume of 10 days without using security function in 15 min chart?

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v4, pine-script-v5

I want to build a pine script which will give me average volume of 10 Days from 09:30 to 16:00 without using the security function. I want to calculate 10 days average volume using the 15 min chart. Help me to code this pine script. I am new to the pine script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=5
indicator("10 Day volume average", overlay = false)

len = input(10)

var float todays_volume = na
var float[] daily_volume_array = array.new_float()

within_time_range = time >= timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, 9, 30) and time < timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, 16, 0)

// Or if you need to account for timezone
//within_time_range = time >= timestamp("GMT+3", year, month, dayofmonth, 9, 30) and time < timestamp("GMT+3", year, month, dayofmonth, 16, 0)

if within_time_range and not within_time_range[1]
    array.unshift(daily_volume_array, todays_volume)
    if array.size(daily_volume_array) > len
        array.pop(daily_volume_array)
    todays_volume := volume
else if within_time_range
    todays_volume += volume

avg_vol = array.avg(daily_volume_array)

plot(avg_vol)
```